# java print string gives pointer number

Tags: java, string, pointers, printing, path-finding

I'm working on a special pathfinding system in java, which needs to print it's path at one point. It's far from done but I ran into a problem. When I run my code it instead prints a pointer towards an string rather then the string itself. Here is the code:

```
public class node {
    int optionnum;
    node[] options;
    String[] dirrections; 
    String[] route; 
    boolean[] visited; 

    public node(){
        options= new node[4];
        dirrections= new String[4];
        route= new String[50];
        for (int i=0;i<50;i++){
            route[i]="";
        }
        visited= new boolean[50];
    }
    public void revmdp(int num){

        visited[num]=true;
        for(int i=0;i<optionnum;i++){
            System.out.println(options[i].route[0]); //how can this be a pointer?
            options[i].revmdp(dirrections[i],num);
    }
public void revmdp(String nroute, int num){
    //System.out.println(route[0]+dirrections[0]);
    if (!visited[num]||nroute.length()<route[num].length()){
        route[num]=nroute;
        visited[num]=true;
        for(int i=0;i<optionnum;i++){
            options[i].revmdp(route+dirrections[i],num);
        }
    }
}
  }
```

output looks like this

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@2d66a22b3;
```

As you can see in the constructor of path I already set the path towards the string "" (empty string). As the string is not yet changed any futher at moment this code is called I would expect it to return "" however it instead gives these weird string pointers. Anybody know what's up?

Note I have already tried to call route[0][0] but java won't allow that.

Comment: How is `route` declared?

Comment: Please follow naming conventions.

Comment: @TedHopp Good point. It's probably an `Object[]`

Comment: route is an String[] as seen in the constructor, and revmdp is reverse markarov desicion procces.

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Comment: @Thijser actually `Object[] route = new String[50];` is perfectly legal java. You haven't showed us the declaration of route, just the assignment/innialization.

Comment: @Thijser - It's _initialized_ to a `String[]`, but how is it _declared_? (However, it's unlikely that this is the problem.)

Comment: options[i].route[0] is for some reason an array of strings

Comment: @MatthewMcveigh that doesn't seam feasibly possible to me, given the above source code.

Comment: That's not a pointer adress, but the hashcode for said object.

Comment: This code does not compile. There is an error at `options[i].revmdp(dirrections[i],num);` because `revmdp` takes a single `int` argument. Please post your actual code, since the output you describe cannot be generated by the code you posted.

Comment: I removed the 2nd revmdp because it's largely the same but I will post it if you want it to compile

Comment: @Cruncher True, but the prefix of '[' indicates it is an array

Comment: When I run this, the output is a string, not an internal identifier like you report.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another `System.out.println` somewhere that is generating that output?

Comment: Griffey Yes I verified it by adding a +"!" to the print as some point. This changed the output to include a ! at the end of every identifier.

Comment: And with the second method added, we can see that you're printing `route+directions[i]` which will try to print the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update 3:** I found it.

```
options[i].revmdp(route+dirrections[i],num);
```

Here you are doing string concatenation on an array and a String. This causes to set `route[num]` in the level of recursion to this concat result.

Comment: The funny thing is if you look one edit back then this answer wouldn't be right.  Look at the header for revmdp() one edit back.

Comment: @MohammadS. and that's why he found the problem now, and not one edit back :). It was unanswerable until this edit

Comment: Yes I assumed that as the print went wrong before the revmdp() was called it would be ok turns out that there is indeed a problem with recursive calls...

Comment: @Thijser the problem is not with recursive calls. The problem is that you're trying to "+" between an array and a String.

Comment: Yes but failing to take into account that the first call goes ok and the next fails makes recursive problems occur.

Comment: @Thijser You have a problem with the fact that, if one recursive call fails, then so do the rest? If you write correct recursion there's no problems (except for potentially hitting max stack length).

Answer (score 1):

Each Java class inerhits from the class `Object`, which implements the default `toString()` method. The Source code of the [default toString()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Object.java#Object.toString%28%29) Method looks like :

```
public String toString() {

        return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());

    }
```

If you do not override the default toString() method, the method above is called.

Comment: But if the actual object is a `String`, then `toString()` is already overridden.